# ERROR: character with byte sequence 0xc4 0x97 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding

I am using a Postgres database with server encoding `WIN1252`. I have configure the client encoding to be Unicode, but I'm still getting this error when connecting via JDBC:

```
ERROR: character with byte sequence 0xc4 0x97 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

Any idea why this might be?

I am using PostgreSQL 14.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit, and Java 1.8.

Comment: Is the server encoding WIN1252? You can see with `SHOW server_encoding;`.

Comment: Yes, the server_encoding is WIN1252

Answer (score 0):

Since your server encoding is `WIN1252`, you cannot store the character `ė` in the database, because that character cannot be encoded in Windows-1252.

You had better create your database with the encoding `UTF8`.